# Qt: How to check if the keyboard focus is on the Qt Application main window?

Tags: c++, qt

How can I check in a method if the Qt application has keyboard focus or not?

Comment: Have a look at [`QApplication::focusChanged()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#focusChanged) and [`QApplication::activeWindow()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#activeWindow).

Comment: @Scheff Thanks for the reply. I don't need to monitor focus, so QApplication::focusChanged() is not required. I just need to check if the keyboard focus is currently on my Qt application window or not. So, QApplication::activeWindow() seems to be what I need. But, I can't access it as QApplication::activeWindow(). Can you please guide?

Comment: _I can't access it as QApplication::activeWindow()._ ??? It's `public static`. Why can't you access it? (`#include <QApplication>` missing?)